# Rails: User not being created with proper default role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, devise, cancancan

In my rails application, I simply have two roles, Admin and User, which I defined in my schema and user model. Here's my schema.rb with users table:

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.integer  "role",                   default: 2
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

Firstly, here is my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    #Defining different roles
    enum role: [:Admin, :User]
    #Users can only have one scholarship application
    has_one :applications
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

My ability model:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
        if user.role = 1
            can :manage, :all
        elsif user.role = 2
            can :manage, Application
            can :manage, User
        else
            can :read, Static_Page
        end
    end
end
```

My users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user
  #Users who are not signed in cannot view users list
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  load_and_authorize_resource

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = current_user
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    #Never trust paramaters from the scary internet, man.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
    end
end
```

In my views, I added some conditions to be shown based on the user's role, such as this:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<h4 class="center"> Welcome <%= current_user.first_name %>!</h4>
<% end %>
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.role = "Admin" %>

<h4 class="center"> You are a <%= current_user.role %>, you can view all applications, edit them, delete users, and more!!</h4>
<% elsif user_signed_in? && current_user.role = "User" %>
<h4 class="center"> Thank you for your interest in our scholarship. As a <%= current_user.role %>, you may create, edit, or delete your scholarship application now that you are signed in.</h4>

<% else %>
<h4 class="center"> Welcome to the Philanthropist's Scholarship Application! Please create an account to apply for our scholarship!</h4>

<% end %>
```

I followed the above logic for an Admin CP (For admins) and Account Settings (For Users) view in my users view- so that the admin CP would show all users like the default rails scaffold for users, whereas the account settings would only show the user info for the current user.

Only problem is, when I create a new user, it always says that the user is an admin, I create a new user, and the role value doesn't seem to be equal to 2 (the "user"), and they're just an admin and can do anything.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use == not = in your view to get the correct functionality. Extra to that your field in your Users table is an integer...

```
t.integer  "role",                   default: 2

<% if user_signed_in? %>
<h4 class="center"> Welcome <%= current_user.first_name %>!</h4>
<% end %>
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.role == 1 %>

<h4 class="center"> You are a <%= current_user.role %>, you can view all applications, edit them, delete users, and more!!</h4>
<% elsif user_signed_in? && current_user.role == 2 %>
<h4 class="center"> Thank you for your interest in our scholarship. As a <%= current_user.role %>, you may create, edit, or delete your scholarship application now that you are signed in.</h4>

<% else %>
<h4 class="center"> Welcome to the Philanthropist's Scholarship Application! Please create an account to apply for our scholarship!</h4>

<% end %>
```

Comment: You can use a helper method to print Admin or User based of if the current_user.role == 1. Will put together the helper for you and edit the post - At the moment from what i can see 
You are a <%= current_user.role %>,
will be a number based on their role number

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you for response. I managed to figure this out last night- I was also missing another key point, I had enum role: [:Admin, :User] but then I had the role in the schema set to 2- but I had nothing set to two because it was 0 indexed, like admin = 0 and user is 1. So, I made it :Guest, :User, :Admin and set the default value to 1. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! glad you got it sorted, it is always a wicked feeling when it all works!